# Can I chose a module to load at runtime in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know lazy loading exists, but all of the examples of lazy loading deal with loading components based on routes.

My app will be hosted on a few different domains, and I need to be able to load HttpInterceptors dynamically at runtime based on the domain, not just the route. So again, not a component that will be shown to a user based on a route, but I need to chose different interceptors based on where the app is loaded at run-time. Is this possible in Angular? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: But I dont want to have to build for each domain. I want to be able to build once, deploy to various domains.

Comment: hmm, if your interceptor has amount of code you tend to lazy load, it's most likely you could redesign this, otherwise saving few KBs in payload won't be worth the readability loss with such approach

Comment: do you know domains ahead of time ? I guess you could have different lazy loaded modules that each import HttpClientModule and thus have their own HttpInterceptor which will overwrite the interceptor defined in root module

Comment: oh and lazy loading components arrived in newer versions of angular where lazy loading modules has been around longer: loadChildren: () => import('./authentication/authentication.module').then( m => m.AuthenticationModule)